# Can I email a file from my phonegap app on ipad?

Tags: ios, email, cordova

Want to build up a csv file, call up the default email app and attach the file...

Can someone give me the skinny!?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the `EmailComposer`plugin.